# Disable Function when parameter type is void

Tags: templates, c++11, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I have a template class looking like this:

```
template <typename T> constexpr bool is_value_passable_v = is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) && !is_polymorphic_v<T>;
template <typename B, typename T> using param_base_t = conditional_t<is_value_passable_v<B>, T, const T&>;

template <typename T> struct param_d
{
    using type = param_base_t<T, T>;
};

template <> struct param_d<void>
{
    using type = void;
};

template <typename T> using param_t = typename param_d<T>::type;

template <class TIn> class CClass
{
    public:
        static constexpr bool use_input_v = !is_same_v<typename TIn::input_t, void>;
        using input_t = conditional_t<use_input_v, param_t<typename TIn::input_t>, void>;

        enable_if_t<use_input_v> Input(input_t i);
};
```

The goal of this code is, to provde different `Input` functions for different template paramters.

- A template parameter with `input_t = int` should result in `void Input(int i)`
- A template parameter with `input_t = std::vector` should result in `void Input(const std::vector& i)`
- A template parameter with `input_t = void` should remove the `Input` function

Compiling this with clang gives

```
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:225:78: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Bp, _Tp>::type;
                                                                             ^~~
```

**Edit 1:**
After adding the line

```
template <typename T> static constexpr bool use_input2_v = use_input_v;
```

and replacing the function declaration with

```
template <typename T = void> enable_if_t<use_input2_v<T>> Input(input_t i)
```

clang complains there's `no matching member function for call to 'Input'`:

```
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = void]: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
template <typename T = void> enable_if_t<use_input2_v<T>> Input(input_t i);
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~     ^
```

**Edit 2:**
Forgot to mention, that this error comes with all three variants of template parameters.

**Edit 3:**
A sample use case for `CClass` could be

```
class CInput0
{
    using input_t = int;
};

class CInput1
{
    using input_t = std::vector<int>;
};

class CInput2
{
    using input_t = void;
};

CClass<CInput0> in0;
CClass<CInput1> in1;
CClass<CInput2> in2;

std::vector<int> i = {1, 2, 3};

in0.Input(3);
in1.Input(i);
//in2.Input() disabled
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `static constexpr bool use_input_v = !is_same<typename TIn::input_t, void>;`?

Comment: Instead of the use_input2_v version? Afaik enable_if can only disable functions based on 'direct' templates.

Comment: `template <typename T> constexpr bool is_value_passable_v = is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) && !is_polymorphic_v<T>;` What's this? It's neither a function nor a class template.

Comment: Oh sorry! It's a c++14 variable template. Forgot the appropriate tag.

Comment: Where does `TIn::input_t` come from? Or asked differently: How are you actually instantiating `CClass`?

Comment: @MikeMB see my Edit #3 :

Comment: As you already suspected, `enable_if` only works on direct template parameters. If you have a template class and want to disable methods based on the class' template parameter, (partial) specialization is the way to go.

Comment: At least with clang 3.5 on fedora 21 this throws a lot of (probably unrelated) compiler errors. A true [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SFINAE`to work, it needs to be working off a dependent type, otherwise there is no substitution failure.  Here is an example:

```
    template <typename Self = CClass<TIn>>
    typename std::enable_if<Self::use_input_v>::type
      Input(typename Self::input_t) { }
```

When a member function is a template, the compiler conditionally creates it based on whether the template parameters work. In your original example, since the whole class is a template, but the method is not, the compiler just sees it as an error with your member function as soon as the class is instantiated. Using a default template parameter is just the trick we need. What we want to test is now considered dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable a function based on the properties of a template parameter, without partial specialization you can use the following pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::vector<int>& value);

template <class TIn> class CClass
{
    public:         
        template <class T =TIn, class PARAM=  std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_same<void,typename T::input_t>::value) ,typename T::input_t > >
        void Input(PARAM i){
            std::cout << "Called Input with parameter: "<< i << std::endl;
        }
};

struct CInput0{ using input_t = int;};
struct CInput1{ using input_t = std::vector<int>;};
struct CInput2{ using input_t = void;};

CClass<CInput0> in0;
CClass<CInput1> in1;
CClass<CInput2> in2;

std::vector<int> i = {1, 2, 3};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::vector<int>& value) {
    for (auto& e:value) {
        out << e;
    } 
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main() {

    in0.Input(3);
    in1.Input(i);
    //in2.Input() disabled
}
```

This is a simplified version of your example, which you should be able to adapt.